# Deselect Stages By Default

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

In Azure Devops multistage YAML pipeline we got multiple environments.
In stages to run normally we do a build and deploy only in QA, so we need to deselect each stage manually. By default all stages are selected is it possible to have exact opposite, where all stages are deselected by default???

[image: select stages]

```
trigger: none
pr: none
stages:
- stage: 'Build'
  jobs:
  - deployment: 'Build'
    pool:
      name: Default
# testing
    environment: INT
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: none
          - powershell: |
              echo "Hello Testing"
              Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
- stage: 'Sandbox'
  jobs:
  - job: 'Sandbox'
    pool:
      name: Default
    steps:
    - checkout: none
# testing
    - powershell: |
        echo "Hello Testing"
- stage: 'Test'
  jobs:
  - job: 'DEV'
    pool:
      name: Default
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - powershell: |
        echo "Hello Testing"
- stage: 'QA'
  dependsOn: ['Test','Test1','Test2']
  jobs:
  - job: 'QA'
    pool:
      name: Default
    steps:
    - checkout: none
      # Testing
    - powershell: |
        echo "Hello Testing"
```

Comment: Hi @Sar. The answer is more like a workaround, beacuse azure devops does not have an out-of-the-box method. Feel free to let me know if it could meet your requirements. You could also submit a suggestion ticket on [Our UserVoice Site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am afraid that there is no UI (like stage to run) method that can meet your needs.

You could try to add parameters to your Yaml Sample.

Here is an example:

```
trigger: none
pr: none

parameters:
- name: stageTest
  displayName: Run Stage test
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: stageBuild
  displayName: Run Stage build
  type: boolean
  default: false

stages:
- ${{ if eq(parameters.stageBuild, true) }}: 
  - stage: 'Build'
    jobs:
    - deployment: 'Build'
      pool:
        name: Default
      environment: INT
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - checkout: none
            - powershell: |
                echo "Hello Testing"
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

- ${{ if eq(parameters.stageTest, true) }}: 
  - stage: Test
    dependsOn: []
    jobs:
    - job: B1
      steps:
      - script: echo "B1"
```

The parameters are used to  determine whether to run these stages. You could add expressions before the stage to check if the parameter value could meet expression.

The default value is false. This means that the stage will not run by default.

Here is the result:

[image]

You can select the stage you need to run by clicking the selection box.

**Update**

Workaround has some **limitations**. When the select stage has depenencies, you need to select all dependent stages to run.

For example:

```
  - stage: 'QA'
    dependsOn: ['Test','Test1','Test2']
```

[image]

On the other hand, I have created a suggestion ticket to report this feature request. Here is the suggestion ticket link: [Pipeline Deselect Stages By Default](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1161188/pipeline-deselect-stages-by-default.html) You could vote and add comment in it .

Comment: if condition is not accepted in main azure pipelines i am right?

Comment: if condition can be used by yaml pipeline， you could refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops. If I misunderstood your question, can you explain it in detail.

Comment: Hi @Sar. Is there any update about this ticket? Could you please check if the workaround could work?

Comment: the work around works well, if used it for only one stage but when i try to use it for multiple stages and select inbetween stages i get some depenency errors

Comment: Hi @Sar. Thanks for your feedback. I could confirm that the workaround has limitations. Please check the update. I also create a suggestion ticket to report the feature.I also hope to realize this feature in the future

Comment: we can't use the "condition" instead of the if ?

Answer (score 1):

I've used this solution to build a nuget-package, and:

- always push packages from master
- conditionally push packages from other branches

Using GitVersion ensures that the packages from other branches get prerelease version numbers, e.g. **2.2.12-my-branch-name.3** or **2.2.12-PullRequest7803.4**. The main branch simply gets **2.2.12**, so the master branch is recognized as a "regular" version.

The reason I'm repeating the answer above, is that I chose to make the stage conditional instead of using an if:

```
trigger:
  - master

parameters:
- name: pushPackage
  displayName: Push the NuGet package
  type: boolean
  default: false

stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
    - job: DoBuild
      steps:
      - script: echo "I'm building a NuGet package (versioned with GitVersion)"

  - stage: Push
    condition: and(succeeded('build'), or(eq('${{ parameters.pushPackage }}', true), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')))
    jobs:
    - job: DoPush
      steps:
      - script: echo "I'm pushing the NuGet package"
```

Like the other answer, this results in a dialog:

[image: Run pipeline - conditional 'Push to NuGet feed]

But what's different from the (equally valid) solution with '${{ if }}', is that the stage is always shown (even if it's skipped):

[image: stage - skipped]